# How do I view my snapshots on Mozilla console?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

So I am new to React and learning it through a project-based course. I am stuck though and hoping you good people will help.

So I added my local data to firestore so I can later fetch it back to my app and add it to my reducer so it's easier to access the data from different devices more easily. The problem I encountered is displaying my document snapshots. Now from the tutorial, he displays his document snapshots but from my end, I get nothing from the log.

Code to add my data to firestore(which is in a firestore file i created) is:

```
export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (
    collectionKey,
    objectsToAdd
) => {
    const collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionKey);
    
    const batch = firestore.batch();
    objectsToAdd.forEach((obj) => {
        const newDocRef = collectionRef.doc();
        batch.set(newDocRef, obj);
    });

    return await batch.commit();
};
```

The code to display my snapshots(which is in a different file i imported my firestore file in) is:

```
class ShopPage extends React.Component {
    unsubscribeFromSnapshot = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        const collectionRef = firestore.collection('collections');
        collectionRef.onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { match } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="shop-page">
                <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview} />
                <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Expected output: A query snapshot of what I get from firestore, ie(an array with 5 query document snapshots).
[screenshot of the expected output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdDNM.jpg

Current output: No log of my snapshot.

Kindly Help!

Comment: If you check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) you can see that `onSnapshot` does not require the `async` notation, that might be what is causing the issue you are facing, try removing it and let me know if it works.

Comment: So I removed the async notation and still cant log my documents. What could be wrong?...The issue is still present.

Comment: What, precisely, do you expect to cause the snapshot?  You've attached a *listener*, but you don't show anything to cause the *event*

Comment: Can you share what is triggering the event as mentioned by LeadDreamer?

Comment: Hello good people, so I edited the question, kindly look it over again and see if I am making more sense please. Thank you guys

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are setting your `onSnapshot` inside your `componentDidMount`, since that is only called once in a component's lifecycle, so it might be a better idea to declare all that outside of it, can you try doing that?

Comment: @ralemos... thank you for the response. So from the tutorial, he puts inside the componentDidMount and it works...this is his output in the console https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdDNM.jpg

Comment: Can you share the tutorial link so I can understand the full picture of what is being done?

Comment: @ralemos...so I switched my default browser to chrome and everything worked perfectly. I believe the problem was Firefox. Everything seems to be working correctly now. Thank you

Comment: Good to know @BrianWambura, please do consider adding that to an answer to your question, that way if more people come accross that problem they can easily find a solution for it and this will also increase your reputation once you mark you answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Thank You @ralemos :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my browser from Mozilla Firefox to Chrome and everything worked fine. I got my snapshot queries logged in the chrome console.